# Set static frequency for the audio file (React-Native application)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio-player, frequency-analysis

I am a react-native developer and I want to create an application for the **Students** and Motto of the application is give peaceful music (Need to play on Bluetooth) from the application, and for this audio I want to maintain the frequency (Means as of now when I play those audio files from the various device it's getting me different output but I want same output from the all the various devices)

I have tried to find the solution but didn't get anything useful, So it will be good if anyone can help me with this point

Answer (score 2):

You could consider mqtt (https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-mqtt), ntp (https://github.com/luneo7/react-native-ntp-sync) and react-native sound libraries (https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound#readme).

With an mqtt broker (you can get free ones with [hivemq](https://info.hivemq.com/mqtt-broker) or [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/)) and the mqtt library installed in all your devices, you can create a channel/group where all devices will be connected and listening every message in this channel/group.

You will need to set a master device.

The shared messages will be the playback instructions eg:

- Instruction 1: Load in buffer the song with url ... `{instruction: 'buffer', songURL: 'https://<song_url>'}`
- Instruction 2: When every device has loaded, send a ready status `{instruction: 'ready', deviceId: '<device_id>'}`
  The master device will be counting all the ready instructions until 100% of devices are ready to play.
- Instruction 3: The master device send the play instruction for all devices with the start date using ntp `{instruction: 'play', startDate: <timestamp>}`. Every device on the channel receives the instruction and calculates the delta between the star date and the local date from ntp and you can do this diff with [moment](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/). With this delta in seconds and the second's length of the song (you can get it with [react-native-sound library API](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/wiki/API#getcurrenttimecallback)) set the time of play with setCurrentTime to the track and play()
- You can send periodical instructions with the getCurrentTime of every device to make more delta comparisons and set the corresponding time in every period.

Hope it helps and glad to hear from you if it worked.